# Allow private/protected Twitter profiles to be seen via Application tokens

Tags: twitter

So I'm building an app which allows to link a twitter user during registration. Now a problem which has been seen is that some twitter users have their profiles set to private and no post can be shown.

This is not a good thing as an admin should directly go to a twitter profile to manually (for now) check if a twitter profile is fake or not.

Now my question: is there a part of the twitter API where you can use tokens to generate a url which will be used to show tweets only for users which authenticated with my app?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this. A protected user must choose to allow another user to follow them in order for the Tweets to be seen. This is not part of the Twitter API.

Comment: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a/obtaining-user-access-tokens 
Through OAuth 1.0a it's possible to read tweets from their timeline. You make the API request on behalf of the user. --- I'm not sure if the other authentication methods allows you to retrieve private tweets. I thought you can only get publicly available tweets regardless if they followed you or not since you are authenticating an application not a user.